# Posting data to php script with sammy.js

Tags: javascript, sammy.js

Im trying to create a contact form by send data to a php script to send mail from a form in a sammy.js app. I've set it up as follows and it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why and get me in the right direction to fix it? Thanks!

html form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#/submitcontact">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="control-group">

            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Your Name:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="from-name">
                    <p class="help-block">Nice to know who the message is from.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Your Email:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" class="input-xlarge" id="from-email">
                <p class="help-block">Supply an email so I can reply.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group"> 
            <label class="control-label" for="input01">Your Message:</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <textarea class="input-xlarge" id="from-msg"></textarea>
                <p class="help-block">Including a message is always nice.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
            <button type="submit" class="btn" style="position:relative;float:center;">Send!</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

On submit it posts to the route #/submitcontact:

```
        this.post('#/submitcontact', function(context) {
            $.post("mail.php", this.params,
                function(data) {
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing each value to function post. Modify the code like this:

```
context = $('form').serialize();
$.post('#/submitcontact', function(context) {
            $.post("mail.php", this.params,
                function(data) {
                    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            });
        });
```

Maybe this could work.